# jQuery Using NEXT and retrieve Title Attr

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got the mouseover working to retrieve the ID.  But trying to use next() to retrieve the title attr (title="01" only) but for some reason it's not working. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','tr[role="row"]',function(){
    var VId = $(this).next('[role="gridcell"]').attr('title');
    $('#TestPanelA').html(VId);
});
```

PHP (this table is generated by jqGrid):

```
<tr role="row" id="1" tabindex="-1" class="jqgrow ui-row-ltr H0">
  <td role="gridcell" style="text-align: left; height: 16px;" title="01" aria-describedby="0Li_A">01</td>
  <td role="gridcell" style="text-align: right; height: 16px;" title="822" aria-describedby="0Li_C">822</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` is for sibling element, you want here a child, you could use `children()`:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','tr[role="row"]',function(){
    var VId = $(this).children('[role="gridcell"]').first().attr('title');
    $('#TestPanelA').html(VId);
});
```

Comment: gah!  I should have known lol.. Many thanks.. NOW that works :)

Answer (score 3):

`next` method is used to retrieve next sibling, so you may use `children` or `find` methods with `:first` selector or the `first` method:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','tr[role="row"]',function(){
    var VId = $(this).children('[role="gridcell"]:first').attr('title');
    $('#TestPanelA').html(VId);
});
```

Comment: that's another interesting way :)  Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var VId = $(this).children('[role="gridcell"]').attr('title');
```

In the event handler $(this) refers to the tr not the td. So you need to lookup through chilren.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QcYMK/)

I hope it helps.